# MySQL table linking 1:n

Tags: mysql, join

*So first up I'm not sure if this is a double post or not because I don't know how the exact approach or feature is called and if it even exist.*

I know that MySQL has a feature called joins 
My plan is to link two MySQL tables in relation 1:n one is t_user the other one t_event.

t_user:

```
CREATE TABLE t_user (
    uId INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

t_event:

```
CREATE TABLE t_event (
    eId INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    members ???,
    ...
)
```

I want the users to "subscribe" to the events and get stored in the `members` column as a list (?). This would be no problem if only one user would subscribe to one event. But I have no idea how to setup the `t_event` table to store more than one user and how to query for all the events a user has "subscribed" for.

Comment: Just a remark: joins (no trailing t) are the foundation of relational databases and basically what makes them relational. I wouldn't describe it as a *MySQL* feature ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done via third table:

```
CREATE TABLE t_eventsusers (
    eId INT(6),
    uId INT(6)
)
```

Comment: Ok.. I'll try it (I hoped there would be a more elegant way of doing this)

Comment: @TheTrueFreeStyle - You'd probably want something like a comma-separated string in a single cell. That'd be the inelegant approach!

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario ^^ Yeah probably but I like JSON formatted arrays :/ So I searched for a way to implement sth. like that.

Comment: MySQL is a _relational_ database, it's all about relations. And this third table as perfectly correct proposed by Giorgi is the relational part. ;)

Comment: @TheTrueFreeStyle, don't do that. It will be nonrelational and bring you a big pain in the future.

Comment: If you need JSON, you probably need it in PHP or some Node.js application. You can create queries, that will output the results in some sort of JSON format later, for storage and speed reasons, do not ever user blobs, comma-separated lists or serialized data.

Comment: @ALL Thx for your advice! You were pretty helpfull :)